# Confusion about how to use the Free-Body Diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

I'm studying Uniform Circular Motion and I came across a question. I'm following a very similar approach but finding a different relationship for the radius of the circle than the textbook solution gives.

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong here and why I'm having a different result?

[image]

Comment: Why do you say that the sum of the weight and the horizontal component of the lift force must point along the wings of the plane?

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean? The horizontal component is the centripetal force and weight goes down. I formed a triangle, can't I?

Comment: But why would you think that the angle in your triangle will be $\theta$?

Comment: Why the angle would change if the directions are the same like moving components of the the same vector around? I'm trying hard to spot my misconception here.

Answer (score 1):

The vector triangle you have drawn is not correct as you have taken the angle between $F_c$ and the resultant vector as $\theta$, which is wrong, it is not $\theta$.
And the most important part you are missing the L's vertical component,  you just can't take one component and ignore the other like that, questions give you sufficient info for solving, they don't give extras(in most cases).
Well the angle which you are considering as $\theta$ in your attempt,  take it as $\alpha$, where $$\alpha=tan^{-1} (\frac{W}{F_c})$$

Comment: It is clearly possible as they're all related. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, you have formed your triangle. Although as @DanDan0101 mentioned, you have also considered that the angle made by the resultant of $\vec F_c$ and $\vec W = m\vec g$ is along the wings of the plane. Let's confirm that.

As given in your textbook,
$$\vec F_c =\vec L\sin(\theta)$$
and, $$\vec W = \vec L\cos(\theta)$$

If we form a right triangle with $\vec F_c$ and $\vec W$, using above statements, angle formed by the resultant ($\alpha$) with $\vec F_c$ will be given by, $$\tan(\alpha) = \frac{\vec W}{\vec F_c}$$ $$\implies \tan(\alpha) = \cot(\theta) = \tan\left(90^{\circ} - \theta\right)$$
Clearly, the angle you have named $\theta$ in your triangle is incorrectly placed. As some others have mentioned, using the method of writing equations with the forces' components will serve you much better in general.

Comment: @TheSpaceGuy W is common notation for work, but from the context provided in the diagram, W here denotes weight. Indeed you have done the same thing, hence I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the W and Fc triangle. You are right in that you can move the vectors around and keep the directions, but you incorrectly assumed the lengths. The W Fc triangle doesn't necessarily have to have the angle theta--what if W was three times as long? How would you know? Free-body diagrams are mainly for keeping track of directions, you can't assume that the vectors as they are drawn are the proper magnitude. Like the textbook does, you should always calculate the magnitudes yourself using summation of forces.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain @DanDan0101 comment

> Why do you say that the sum of the weight and the horizontal component of the lift force must point along the wings of the plane?

which shows your misconseption.

The vector equation between your forces is
$$\vec{F}_c=\vec{W}+\vec{L}$$
this is represented either by the diagram

[image]

or by

[image]

You are adding $\vec{W}$ to $\vec{L}$ to get $\vec{F}_c$, thus you either need vector $\vec{W}$ to be attached to end of the vector $\vec{L}$ (representing equation $\vec{F}_c=\vec{L}+\vec{W}$) or the other way around (representing equation $\vec{F}_c=\vec{W}+\vec{L}$). Resulting vector  $\vec{F}_c$ then closes the diagram.

The diagram you draw actually represents vector equation
$$\vec{T}=\vec{W} + \vec{F}_c,$$
where I have used $\vec{T}$ as representing diagonal vector in your diagram. This can be rewritten
$$\vec{T}=\vec{W} + \vec{F}_c=\vec{W} + (\vec{W}+\vec{L})=2\vec{W}+\vec{L}$$
This is alright, but here is the problem: you do not know (without computation) angles between vector $\vec{T}=2\vec{W}+\vec{L}$ and other two vectors $\vec{W}$ and $\vec{F}_c$. You assumed one angle of the triangle to be $\theta$, but is it? From the picture and formulation of the problem, you can directly see only angles between vectors $\vec{W}$, $\vec{L}$ and $\vec{F}_c$.

Answer (score 0):

It is the wrong angle in your triangle that you have labeled $\theta$. It should have been the other corner. This will flip your tan-expression, giving you the correct result.